# Laravel: Error [PDOException]: Could not Find Driver in PostgreSQL

Tags: php, database, postgresql, laravel, syntax-error

I'm trying to connect with PostgreSQL database through Laravel in order to do a php artisan migrate but doesn't seem to be directed since it's reading the database name of MySQL.

Here are the commands from database.php:

```
'connections' => array(

    'sqlite' => array(
        'driver'   => 'sqlite',
        'database' => __DIR__.'/../database/production.sqlite',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ),

    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'database',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),

    'pgsql' => array(
        'driver'   => 'pgsql',
        'host'     => 'localhost',
        'database' => 'postgres',
        'username' => 'postgres',
        'password' => 'root',
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
        'schema'   => 'public',
    ),

    'sqlsrv' => array(
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => 'localhost',
        'database' => 'database',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ),

),
```

If I remove the MySQL paths I'll get:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
Database [mysql] not configured.
```

---

**EDIT:**
When trying to do php artisan migrate I get a 'PDOException: could not find driver'. I'm using WAMP and I'm in Win8.1. Using PostgreSQL as database.

---

**EDIT:**
Have experimented a series of alternative solutions but I'm still ought to get this solved.
The `php.ini` file was checked in Apache, WAMP (from php folder) and PostgreSQL. The `extension_dir` is correct as it being -> `extension_dir = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/"`

The `extension=pdo_pgsql.dll` and `extension=pgsql.dll` are uncommented.

Done the `PATH` trick in the 'System Variables' and rebooted. No chance.

Thanks for the help so far.

These are my drivers `php_pdo_driver.h` & `php_pdo.h` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\EnterpriseDB-ApachePHP\php\SDK\include\ext\pdo`

Information from phpinfo:

> PHP Version 5.5.12
>
> Compiler  MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012) Configure Command  cscript /nologo
>   configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--disable-isapi"
>   "--enable-debug-pack" "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql"
>   "--without-pi3web"
>   "--with-pdo-oci=C:\php-sdk\oracle\x64\instantclient10\sdk,shared"
>   "--with-oci8=C:\php-sdk\oracle\x64\instantclient10\sdk,shared"
>   "--with-oci8-11g=C:\php-sdk\oracle\x64\instantclient11\sdk,shared"
>   "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared"
>   "--with-mcrypt=static" "--disable-static-analyze" "--with-pgo"

Comment: If database is the name of your database then you are using a reserved word as your database name

Comment: My PostgreSQL database name is postgres as indicated in the code^

Comment: Awesome, totally misread your post. Are you sure laravel is trying to connect to your postgres database as default?

Comment: I don't think so :( it seems it's trying to connect to MySQL by default and I'd like to figure out how to. Guess the user sgt as figured it out. Thanks a lot, my friend.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Be sure to configure the `'default'` key in `app/config/database.php`

For postgres, this would be `'default' => 'postgres',`

If you are receiving a `[PDOException] could not find driver` error, check to see if you have the correct PHP extensions installed.  You need `pdo_pgsql.so` and `pgsql.so` installed and enabled.  Instructions on how to do this vary between operating systems.

For Windows, the `pgsql` extensions should come pre-downloaded with the official PHP distribution.  Just edit your `php.ini` and uncomment the lines `extension=pdo_pgsql.so` and `extension=pgsql.so`

Also, in `php.ini`, make sure `extension_dir` is set to the proper directory.  It should be a folder called `extensions` or `ext` or similar inside your PHP install directory.

Finally, copy `libpq.dll` from `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.*\` into `C:\wamp\bin\apache*\bin` and restart all services through the WampServer interface.

If you still get the exception, you may need to add the postgres `\bin` directory to your `PATH`:

1. System Properties -> Advanced tab -> Environment Variables
2. In 'System variables' group on lower half of window, scroll through and find the `PATH` entry.
3. Select it and click Edit
4. At the end of the existing entry, put the full path to your postgres bin directory.  The bin folder should be located in the root of your postgres installation directory.
5. Restart any open command prompts, or to be certain, restart your computer.

This should hopefully resolve any problems.  For more information see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php
- http://webcheatsheet.com/php/install_and_configure.php#extsetup

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Please check the edit part in my post. BTW, the default database path was my first issue that was taken care already, the PDO driver problem came right after.

Comment: The DLL files exist in the extensions folder right? Also, try uncommenting another DLL: `extension=php_pdo.dll` That's the main PDO driver that the database specific ones rely on.

Comment: Yes they do exist in that folder. Don't have the `extension=php_pdo.dll` in the `ext` nor in the `php.ini`

Comment: Can you make a quick php script with `phpinfo();`?  It'll give you the actual extension directory and php.ini that's being loaded.  There might be a conflict going on.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I'll copy/paste the info in the 1st post. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you need the whole thing though or just specific parts of it?

Comment: Don't paste the whole thing.  I'm curious about the `extension_dir` setting and the loaded configuration file.  Also, you should have a list in there of all the extensions that are being loaded; are the `pgsql` ones showing up there?

Comment: `extension_dir` -> `c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/` It seems there's hardly any reference to pgsql. It stats the only PDO drivers enabled are from mysql and sqlite. Don't see reference to the extensions other than the extension_dir. Thank you.

Comment: What about the line that says which `php.ini` is being loaded?  The last thing I can think of is that its loading a `php.ini` that doesn't have the extension lines in it.  If that ends up being fine you might want to check out Laravel Homestead - it makes it very easy to get a development VirtualBox set up and working.

Comment: Loaded Configuration File:
    `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini` ... checked and it has -> `extension_dir = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/"`

Comment: Ok, I set up WampServer and postgres on my Windows machine to test this out.  Figured it out - copy `libpq.dll` from `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12` into `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin`, and restart all services through WampServer.  The pgsql extensions will now load, and the driver exception should be resolved.

Comment: Thanks for all the work my friend. Really. I'd give you reputation points but it seems I need to have over 15 myself. Your solution didn't work so I did a fresh installation of everything, cleared the registry and now it finally works!!! I thought I was gonna quit PostgreSQL and move to MySQL. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Note that, for those using Apache or other web server, one needs to restart Apache for the changes to take effect: `sudo systemctl restart httpd.service`

Comment: If one is using php-fpm they need to restart it, apart from restarting web server (nginx/apache)

Comment: `'default' => 'pgsql'` not `postgres`

Comment: damn you libpq.dll, you get me every time. :D

Answer (score 49):

For `PDOException: could not find driver` for `MySQL`, and if it is `Debian` based OS,

```
sudo apt-get -y install php5-mysql
```

Comment: And if you're using PostgreSQL on a modern Debian-based OS, it's `sudo apt-get -y install php7.0-pgsql`.

Answer (score 42):

For PHP 7 in Ubuntu you can also do:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-pgsql
```

So, now you can do not uncomment lines in `php.ini`

**UPD:**
I have a same error, so problem was not in driver.
I changed my `database.ini`, but every time I saw an error.
And I change database config in `.env` and errors gone.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me on Ubuntu (tried uncommenting lines in php.ini to no effect)

Comment: solved with this, in my case use `sudo apt-get install php7.1-pgsql`

Comment: thank you.
solved with this, in my case use 
`sudo apt-get install php7.4-pgsql`

Answer (score 8):

I realize this is an old question but I found it in a Google search so I'm going to go ahead and answer just in case someone else runs across this. I'm on a Mac and had the same issue, but solved it by using [HomeBrew](http://brew.sh). Once you've got it installed, you can just run this command:

```
brew install php56-pdo-pgsql
```

And replace the 56 with whatever version of PHP you're using without the decimal point.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php-gd php-mysql
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. This is what worked for me.

There are 2 php.ini files:

- C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin
- C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12

NOTE: This is using my version of PHP and Apache, change to what yours are.

The php.ini file located in the both folders is what you need to update, the extentions:

- extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
- extension=php_pgsql.dll

These are what you need to uncomment (remove the ; symbol).

Restart both Wamp and the Command Prompt.

Hopefully it will work for you :).

Comment: Finally! I was trying it for 2 hours on Windows 10 Wamp Server, and the problem was that Wamp's options affects only the php.ini file in the apache folder, but not in the php folder. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-pgsql
```

Answer (score 4):

I got this problem too. I have solved this issue already. If u are using Wamp then perform the following steps.

> 1. Go to `wamp64/www/bin/php/php*` (where `*` is the php version you are using)
> 2. Edit file php and uncomment this line by removing the semicolon:

```
;extension=pdo_pgsql to extension=pdo_pgsql
```

> 3. Save and restart your Wamp server

If it does not work, please check your `.env` and config/database again.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error on PHP 7.3.7 docker with laravel:

This works for me

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev && docker-php-ext-install pdo pgsql pdo_pgsql
```

This will install the pgsql and pdo_pgsql drivers.

Now run this command to uncomment the lines extension=pdo_pgsql.so and extension=pgsql.so from php.ini

```
sed -ri -e 's!;extension=pdo_pgsql!extension=pdo_pgsql!' $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini

sed -ri -e 's!;extension=pgsql!extension=pgsql!' $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini
```

Answer (score 3):

[image: You should remove the comment before extension on your driver.]

The driver came disactivated by default you should active by yourself. after that it will work well.

I hope this do.

Answer (score 2):

Solved after 3 hours... 
I am using WAMP (PHP 7.2.4), PostgreSQL 10, Laravel 5.6.29. 
Loaded PHP extensions (pgsql, pdo_pgsql) from Wampserver 3.3, then I was able to connect to the PostgreSQL server with a simple php testcode from the www directory. But `$ php artisan migrate` still returned

> PDOException::("could not find driver")

I checked the shell (git bash for windows) with `$ php --ini`, that returned C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.4\php.ini instead of c:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.33\bin\php.ini, loaded by WAMP
So you have to uncomment pgsql and pdo_pgsql extensions also in C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.4\php.ini, and then migrate will work ...

Answer (score 2):

In Linux(Ubuntu) just install the driver like so:

```
sudo apt-get install php-pgsql
```

This will install the driver with using your php current version.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu like 20.04+ just install:

```
sudo apt install php-pgsql
```

Remember to install `apache2` and `php` before. It'll put the drivers in the right path on installation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Wamp in Windows, you have to edit your `php.ini` file directly from the PHP folder which usually is `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php8.0.13` and need to uncomment extensions by removing `;` in  front of these extensions:

1. `extension=pdo_pgsql`
2. `extension=pgsql`
3. check your php path in environment variables.
4. restart your wamp and restart your cmd or vs code if using vs code CMD

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Docker you can add the below code inside `php/Dockerfile`. It'll install `pdo` `pgsql` `pdo_pgsql` that are necessary for connecting PHP to PostgreSQL.

```
FROM php:8.0.3-fpm
RUN apt-get update

# Install useful tools
RUN apt-get -y install apt-utils nano wget dialog vim

# Install important libraries
RUN echo "\e[1;33mInstall important libraries\e[0m"
    RUN apt-get -y install --fix-missing \
    apt-utils \
    build-essential \
    git \
    curl \
    libcurl4 \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    libbz2-dev \
    locales \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev

RUN echo "\e[1;33mInstall important docker dependencies\e[0m"
RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    exif \
    pcntl \
    bcmath \
    ctype \
    curl \
    iconv \
    xml \
    soap \
    pcntl \
    mbstring \
    tokenizer \
    bz2 \
    zip \
    intl

# Install Postgre PDO
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql
```

Answer (score 0):

For those wanting to use Postgresql on OpenSuse (and co), try the following:

```
zypper --no-refresh in php5-pgsql
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8 PC with Laragon 3.4.0 180809, I faced the same issue. It happened in my case because I updated Laragon and it added a new version of PHP. So in `laragon/bin/php/` I actually had two directories:

- `php-7.1.20-Win32-VC14-x64`
- `php-7.1.7-Win32-VC14-x64`

I added `7.1.20` into my `PATH` variable. But in my Command Console, running `php --ini` was showing that the path actually was fetching from the older one: `php-7.1.7-Win32-VC14-x64`. So I deleted the old one (for safety, I put it in Recycle Bin). But Laragon failed to start after that.

So, in `laragaon/etc/apache2/mod_php.conf`, I changed the path to the latest PHP version. Then restarted Laragon and the issue is resolved.

Reference: [How to add another PHP version - Laragon Forum](https://forum.laragon.org/topic/166/tutorial-how-to-add-another-php-version/14)

Answer (score -1):

Old thread I know,  but I lost a couple of hours of my life with this.  You also need to set the DB info in the .env file.  You don't *have* to specify the driver here because the default specified in database.php is used (I think).  I was struggling because it had `DB_CONNECTION=mysql` in the .env file and I was using pgsql.

Answer (score -1):

Just run this command

```
sudo apt-get -y install php*-mysql
```

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me:

```
$ sudo apt-get -y install php5.6-pgsql
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

I am working with 32bit Ubuntu 14

Answer (score -2):

I see you are using Windows. I was not able to fix this with enabling any of the extensions that come with my Windows WAMP Server. I tried PDO_ODBC and others and even found the [Microsoft Official PDO_SQLSRV](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098).

The solution for me was to install the PDO_SQLSRV drivers from a 3rd party website. I found the drivers through 
http://robsphp.blogspot.nl/2012/06/unofficial-microsoft-sql-server-driver.html

I usually don't use DLLs from random websites, but I was desperate and this worked for me. Hoping it might save others numerous hours of frustration.

Answer (score -4):

Using Laravel V **5.5.39** with Php **7.1.12** is working fine, but later (newer) php versions cause the problem. So, change Php version and you will get the solution **100%** .