# Laravel: Error [PDOException]: Could not Find Driver in PostgreSQL?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, laravel-5

I am trying to connect PostgreSQL with Laravel 5.0 but facing exception "Could not Find Driver in PostgreSQL".

I have tried this solution but cannot connected with PostgreSQL

[stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25336292/3520377)

My database.php config file is following

```
'default' => 'pgsql'

            'pgsql' => [
                'driver'   => 'pgsql',
                'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
                'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
                'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forgeUser'),
                'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '****'),
                'charset'  => 'utf8',
                 'prefix'   => '',
                'schema'   => 'public',
                'port'     => 5432,
            ]
```

PDO extensions are enabled in php.ini

```
extension=php_pdo.dll

extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
```

when i run following command

> php artisan migrate

it gives error

```
[PDOException] could not find driver
```

Its working fine when we connect PostgreSQL with Core PHP.

is there any driver still missing in Laravel? Please guide me.

Thank You

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

You must be `ssh`'d into your homestead or vagrant box. Then try to migrate.

Comment: Good catch. This is not outlined in the documentation though.

Comment: Yeah. Documentation is great but it's impossible to be absolutely 100% thorough ;)