# creating database from postgreSQL with symfony

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, pdo, mapbender3

I am working with [mapbender3](http://mapbender3.org) which is developed in symfony2 on my local machine. I am asked to connect the application to a remote potgreSQL server. Following is the configuration in the **parameters.yml** file.

```
parameters:
    database_driver:   pdo_pgsql
    database_host:     192.168.3.100
    database_port:     5434
    database_name:     idc_core
    database_path:     ~
    database_user:     *******
    database_password: *******

    mailer_transport:  smtp
    mailer_host:       localhost
    mailer_user:       ~
    mailer_password:   ~
```

But when I run the command:

```
php app/console doctrine:database:create
```

I keep getting the below error

```
could not create database for connection named "idc_core"
cound not find driver
```

I am using WAMP server on windows 7 and the driver pdo_pgsql shows active and running on my local computer.

I have checked **phpinfo()** and it displayed **pdo_pgsql** as enabled but when I run `php -m` in commandline to see the modules compiled in,

I can see **PDO**, **pdo_mysql** and **pdo_sqlite** but not **pdo_pgsql**

Comment: It seems you don't have `pdo_pgsql` in your php (you can verify it with `phpinfo()`)

Comment: Is the "extension=php_pgsql.dll" extension uncommented in php.ini?

Comment: @DonCallisto `pdo_pgsql` is loaded and enabled in `phpinfo()`

Comment: @devz yes, the line is uncommented in php.ini

Comment: Are there any errors if you turn on Startup Errors in your php.ini and run php.exe in the commandline?

Comment: @devz I uncommented `display_startup_errors` in `php.ini`. What exactly do I need to run to see if any error is displayed?

Comment: When I run `php -m` in commandline to see the modules compiled in, I can see PDO, pdo_mysql and pdo_sqlite and not pdo_pgsql. So how can I include it there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add **pdo_pgsql** extension into the **CLI** config of your php in

> yourPhpDirectory/cli/php.ini

**CLI** uses this config to work in command line, not the one for apache. This is the reason why `phpinfo();` shows you **pdo_pgsql** and `php -m` not. Also under Windows OS you should restart your command line tool to see differences after any config changes.

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to configure the `'default'` key in `app/config/database.php`

For postgres, this would be `'default' => 'postgres',`

If you are receiving a `[PDOException] could not find driver` error, check to see if you have the correct PHP extensions installed.  You need `pdo_pgsql.so` and `pgsql.so` installed and enabled.  Instructions on how to do this vary between operating systems.

For Windows, the `pgsql` extensions should come pre-downloaded with the official PHP distribution.  Just edit your `php.ini` and uncomment the lines `extension=pdo_pgsql.so` and `extension=pgsql.so`

Also, in `php.ini`, make sure `extension_dir` is set to the proper directory.  It should be a folder called `extensions` or `ext` or similar inside your PHP install directory.

Finally, copy `libpq.dll` from `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.*\` into `C:\wamp\bin\apache*\bin` and restart all services through the WampServer interface.

If you still get the exception, you may need to add the postgres `\bin` directory to your `PATH`:

1. System Properties -> Advanced tab -> Environment Variables
2. In 'System variables' group on lower half of window, scroll through and find the `PATH` entry.
3. Select it and click Edit
4. At the end of the existing entry, put the full path to your postgres bin directory.  The bin folder should be located in the root of your postgres installation directory.
5. Restart any open command prompts, or to be certain, restart your computer.

This should hopefully resolve any problems.  For more information see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php
- http://webcheatsheet.com/php/install_and_configure.php#extsetup

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25336292/1045444

Answer (score 2):

1. Enable both extensions `php_pdo_pgsql` and `php_pgsql` in `php.ini` (the one for the CLI):

   ```
   extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
   extension=php_pgsql.dll
   ```
2. Ensure that "Port" and "Login Credentials" for the remote server are correct by testing from a database administration tool, like Adminer.