# Laravel 5 + PostgreSQL: "Database [postgres] not configured." Error

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, laravel-5, artisan-migrate

I'm trying to get started with Laravel + PostgreSQL and been following the [database tutorial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database).

Unfortunately, after updating the database configuration file and running `php artisan migrate`, the following error appears:

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Database [postgres] not configured.
```

What puzzles me is that I didn't specify the "postgres" database in the configuration, but another database I set through cPanel, say "example_database".

---

Here's some relevant parts of my `/config/database.php` configuration:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'postgres')
```

And inside the `connections` array of the same file:

```
'pgsql' => [
        'driver'   => 'pgsql',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'example_database'), // This seems to be ignored
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'example_username'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'example_password'),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
        'schema'   => 'public'
    ],
```

The actual database credentials I'm using are working perfectly on my SQL Workbench client, so this seems to be a Laravel config problem. Any ideas? I have searched around for at least an hour to no avail.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You have to enter your configuration in the `.env` file.

The configuration you made will only be loaded if they are not already defined in `.env`

You need to use `pgsql` instead of `postgres`.

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=DB_NAME
DB_USERNAME=USER
DB_PASSWORD=PW
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I've made the change in the .env file but the error is the same. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: @FranciscoH. I just updated my answer. rename `postgress` to `pgsql`.

Comment: Setting `DB_CONNECTION=pgsql` gives the following error: `could not find driver`. I set it as `DB_CONNECTION=postgres` based on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25336292/1467941

Comment: Did you also have checked if the pdo postgress driver is installed and loaded correctly?

Comment: That was exactly the issue, Fiete. Also, `DB_CONNECTION=pgsql` works now after installing pdo_pgsql. Silly mistake on my part. Thanks a lot!

Comment: "You need to use pgsql instead of postgres." This was hard to find information! Thanks.

Comment: This answer works for me perfectly. I am using ssh with homestead on a Linux machine.

Answer (score 7):

Laravel sometimes caches your configurations. If you run into this problem while everything looks alright try running

`php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question and it already has an answer; however, here is an small explanation why:

If you check your `database.php` in the `config` directory, you will see that you have few connections types, including `pgsql`. So, the key have to match to the `DB_CONNECTION` in `.env` file. You can definitely replace `pqsql` connection key with `postgres`, and it will work on the same way.

However, I would recommend replacing the value DB_CONNECTION, instead of modifying the config.

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
```