# PDO exception could not find driver in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I was trying to execute a migrate command in laravel 5. But it shows a PDOException error. I changed database.php file to the following:

```
  'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
            'engine'    => null,
        ]
```

Comment: Have you defined any of the database variables in the `.env` file as these are used if present and then it falls back to the ones you have entered there. What's the full error message you get?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Is this your case?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver

Comment: james thank you for reply .... error like that "[PDOException] could not find driver". i using php artisan migrate command in terminal

Comment: i am using ubuntu 14.04

Comment: amir , yes my case look like this... but l am also uncomment extension in php.ini file

Comment: You may want to double check that you have the package `php5-mysql` installed.

Comment: i am using xampp. and it's place in opt folder. and my source folder is opt/lampp/htdocs. and my localhost/phpmyadmin is perfectly run.

Comment: it's possible cannot get mysql folder path or else... because i am using xampp and set setup in opt/lampp/htdocs folder. normally localhost install in var/www/html folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for simple solution, I had same issue & this worked for me..

When you run php artisan from terminal, you invoke php5-cli package.

To run artisan with XAMPP's php you need to use:

/opt/lampp/bin/php artisan migrate

But make sure your /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini is properly configured to enable pdo_mysql

Answer (score 7):

For PDOException: could not find driver for MySQL, and if it is Debian based OS,

```
sudo apt-get -y install php5-mysql
```

For more information read this post [PDO Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329302/laravel-error-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver-in-postgresql/27173665#27173665)

Comment: already remove comment in php.ini file  ==>> extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll , extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll , extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll

Answer (score 1):

Possible Reason :

1. Check phpinfo() whether pdo installed or not,if not then enabled from php.ini

Note : PDO driver installed when we install php., php version can also be issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should setup your `.env` file. If you do not have one, just rename `.env.example` to `.env` and use it. Edit it like this:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/configuration#environment-configuration

Comment: i alreay create .env file  APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=sdfdsafdsafsdafasfsfas

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

Comment: So, you still get an error message? If yes, can you show me full error message then?

Comment: i will use "php artisan migrate" command . it's show  [PDOException] could not find driver error msg.

Comment: Do you have this line in `database.php`: `'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),`? Do you have MySQL installed on your local machine and can you connect to it with MySQL Workbench or similar tool?

Comment: yes, "'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql')" this line available in database.php file. and yes i have install mysql installed in my local machine. i'm not using any tools like this.

Comment: any problem in laravel installation or same alse

Comment: I don't think a problem in a Laravel here. It seems you don't have MySQL installed or something.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me "sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite".