# PDOException could not find driver

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm getting this error when i try to migrate. Im trying to run my project on postgres on MAC OS. Any suggestion how can i do this? I uncomment this in php.ini
 but i nothing happend.

```
   extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
    extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO exception could not find driver in laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36370074/pdo-exception-could-not-find-driver-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this line in `php.ini`

```
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

and then install the `PDO` by running following command:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```

**EDIT**

and also try to restart your computers sometimes it happens that restarting apache did not reloads the configuration

Comment: im not using linux, im using macos

Comment: so try to restart your computers sometimes it happens that restarting apache did not reloads the configuration