# Laravel MySQL database setup error

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, pdo

I want to use a MySQL database with my Laravel 5.2 framework. I'm not able to access phpMyAdmin after I run `php artisan serve` and open a localhost page.

My `.env` file :

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=people
DB_USERNAME=pftest
DB_PASSWORD="pftest_2016#9"
```

After doing this, I ran `php artisan migrate` and got the following error:

```
[PDOException] could not find driver
```

Following which, I have installed the `php-mysql` extension and checked for its presence in `php.ini` file.
But I'm still getting the following error :

```
[PDOException]  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

So what is the issue and how to solve it?

Comment: Check the password , "pftest_2016#9" or pftest_2016#9 ?

Comment: Run `php --ini` from the command line and make sure it is using the same .ini file you think it is using.

Comment: @kirangadhvi its not same.. read the error.. my error is : [PDOException]  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Comment: @Pitchinnate After I ran php --ini , I found the configuration file pointing at this place: /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini. Where is it suppose to point ?? how to know which path its suppose to point ??

Comment: @s_user hey please check this link and check answer i think that's what you looking for.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329302/laravel-error-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver-in-postgresql

Comment: @kirangadhvi it dint help. Btw I'm working on ubuntu,php7,laravel5.2

Comment: @s_user is that the same .ini file you checked to see if mysql extension is enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `.env` file, set

```
APP_ENV=local
DB_PORT=3306
```

and then run `php artisian migrate --env="local"`

Same is valid for dev,production env.

Comment: artisian shoud be renamed to 'artisan'