# PDO Exception in Connector.php line 55: could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Running a website (Laravel 5.1, Ubuntu 14.04, PHP 7, mysql 5.7).  It was working fine till yesterday, when I started getting the following message while trying to sign up users:

> PDOException in Connector.php line 55: could not find driver.

```
1.  in Connector.php line 55
2.  at PDO->__construct('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_name', 'user_name', 'Pwd', array('0', '2', '0', false, false)) inConnector.php line 55
3.  at Connector->createConnection('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_name', array('driver'
=> 'mysql', 'host' => 'localhost', 'database' => 'db_name', 'username' => 'user_name', 'password' => 'Pwd', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => false, 'name' => 'mysql'), array('0', '2', '0', false, false)) in MySqlConnector.php line 22
4.  at MySqlConnector->connect(array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => 'localhost', 'database' => 'db_name', 'username' => 'user_name', 'password' => 'Pwd', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => false, 'name' => 'mysql')) in compiled.php line 11418
5.  at ConnectionFactory->createSingleConnection(array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => 'localhost', 'database' => 'db_name', 'username' => 'user_name', 'password' => 'Pwd', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => false, 'name' => 'mysql')) in compiled.php line 11414
6.  at ConnectionFactory->make(array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => 'localhost', 'database' => 'db_name', 'username' => 'user_name', 'password' => 'Pwd', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => false), 'mysql') incompiled.php line 11329
7.  at DatabaseManager->makeConnection('mysql') in compiled.php line 11284
8.  at DatabaseManager->connection(null) in DatabasePresenceVerifier.php line 107
9.  at DatabasePresenceVerifier->table('users') in DatabasePresenceVerifier.php line 47
10. at DatabasePresenceVerifier->getCount('users', 'email', 'testy@testymctesterson2.com', null, null, array()) in Validator.php line 1070
11. at Validator->validateUnique('email', 'testy@testymctesterson2.com', array('users'), object(Validator)) in Validator.php line 362
12. at Validator->validate('email', 'unique:users') in Validator.php line 314
13. at Validator->passes() in Validator.php line 335
14. at Validator->fails() in AuthController.php line 82
15. at AuthController->postRegister(object(Request))
16. at call_user_func_array(array(object(AuthController), 'postRegister'), array(object(Request))) in compiled.php line 8880
17. at Controller->callAction('postRegister', array(object(Request))) in compiled.php line 8949
18. at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(AuthController), object(Route), 'postRegister') in compiled.php line 8929
19. at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
20. at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 9600
21. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in RedirectIfAuthenticated.php line 41
22. at RedirectIfAuthenticated->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
23. at call_user_func_array(array(object(RedirectIfAuthenticated), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9592
24. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
25. at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 9582
26. at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 8930
27. at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(AuthController), object(Route), object(Request), 'postRegister') in compiled.php line 8915
28. at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController', 'postRegister') in compiled.php line 7864
29. at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 7835
30. at Route->run(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 7488
31. at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
32. at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 9600
33. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
34. at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 9582
35. at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 7489
36. at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 7477
37. at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 7462
38. at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2307
39. at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
40. at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 9600
41. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2925
```

php ini looks like this:

> `Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.0/cli Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini, /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini`

and 
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini has the line:

> extension=pdo_mysql.so

Artisan tinker works fine and is able to access and write to the database.

We recently upgraded mysql, but that was a few days before this started happening, and I don't know what might have changed on the server to cause this error.

Comment: You gave the stacktrace, but what was the actual Exception message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: Error \[PDOException\]: Could not Find Driver in PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329302/laravel-error-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver-in-postgresql)

Comment: edited to put in the exception