# connecting postgres with laravel

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Hello i'm trying to connect laravel 5.4 with postgres, after updating the database configuration file and running `php artisan migrate`, the following error appears:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
 could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where t
 able_schema = public and table_name = migrations)
[PDOException]
 could not find driver
```

this is my `.env` file

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=Portail
DB_USERNAME=php
DB_PASSWORD=php
```

and this is my `database.php` file

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'),
 'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'Portail'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'php'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'php'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer', ],
```

and i use phpPgAdmin normally

Comment: Try to set DB_HOST = localhost  instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: do not work too

Comment: You probably do not have PHP module pgsql installed.

Comment: i use phpPgAdmin normally with php_pgsql

Comment: i use wampserver 3.0.6 64 bit and php 7

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329302/laravel-error-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver-in-postgresql

May helps you

Comment: `extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll`
`extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll`
`extension=php_pgsql.dll`
`;extension=php_phpdbg_webhelper.dll` `;extension_dir = "ext"`
`extension_dir ="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/ext/"`

Comment: and i copy libpq.dll but don't work

Answer (score 13):

sudo apt-get install php-pgsql. This is the command to install php pgsql driver in linux

Comment: i use windows and my php_pgsql work i connect php with phppgadmin without laravel but with laravel don't work

Comment: That fixed my problem. I was trying `php artisan migrate` and got the error: `“could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')”`

Installing the driver to Ubuntu 20 fixed the problem. 
Thanks @JohnSimon

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem using on Ubuntu18.04 using php7.4
Solution:

- First check you PHP version with `php -v`, in my case the version come out to be php7.4   so installed the necessary driver with `apt-get install php7.4-pgsql`
- Finally restart the PHP server

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution there are two php.ini files

- C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin
- C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10

i must do uncommented php_pdo_pgsql.dll and php_pgsql.dll in the two files
thanks for your help all

Comment: For those using XAMPP, Navigate to `C:\xampp\php` folder and open the php.ini file and Then enable the `pdo_pgsql` and `pgsql` extensions by removing the preceding ; (semicolon) on these lines;
`extension=pdo_pgsql`
`extension=pgsql`
For more details, visit https://neutrondev.com/setup-postgresql-in-xampp-for-windows/

Answer (score 0):

For those using XAMPP, Navigate to `C:\xampp\php` folder and open the php.ini file and Then enable the `pdo_pgsql` and `pgsql` extensions by removing the preceding ; (semicolon) on these lines;
`extension=pdo_pgsql`
`extension=pgsql`
For more details, visit https://neutrondev.com/setup-postgresql-in-xampp-for-windows/