# laravel cannot find driver (after completing migrations)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

This is not the usual "cannot find driver" error message with Laravel. I am able to successfully create migrations and see them reflected in the database. However when I attempt to insert or select, i get the following error:

```
 QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
could not find driver (SQL: insert into .....
```

this is from my migration file:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('vendors', function (Blueprint $table) {
             $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('vendor_name');
            $table->string('contact_name');
            $table->string('phone_number');
            $table->string('alt_phone_number');P
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('address');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

and this is from my store() method in my RESTful Model:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        Vendor::create(request(['vendor_name', 'contact_name', 'phone_number', 'alt_phone_number', 'email','address']));
        this.index();
    }
```

I know the request is getting the data, as I am about to do a `dd()` and view the contents perfectly fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329302/laravel-error-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver-in-postgresql

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/php-artisan-migrate-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver-problem

Comment: What is `this.index()`? That is not valid PHP.

Comment: Does your `Vendor` model have a `$connection` property defined?

Comment: i created the Model with eloquent, so while it is not explicitly defined, i believe it is implicitly

Comment: that is inside the controller so it is just me calling the index method to return to the '/Vendors/' screen

Comment: @ashanrupasinghe i already have done all of that, I would not be able to run the migrations otherwise.

Comment: please show db setting in ,env file

Comment: what is db you are used?

Comment: The `this.index()` should be `$this->index()`, that is what @patricus was getting at.

Comment: What does your `Vendor` class look like and what is the full stack trace for that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:
   For PDOException: could not find driver for MySQL, and if it is Debian based 
     OS,

```
sudo apt-get -y install php5-mysql
```

Comment: im not using Ubuntu, and i already have Pgsql set up, i would not be able to run the migrations if i didnt.