# Could migrate database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

php artisan migrate

In Connection.php line 664:

could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where t
  able_schema = homestead and table_name = migrations)

In Connector.php line 67:

> could not find driver

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: Error \[PDOException\]: Could not Find Driver in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329302/laravel-error-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver-in-postgresql)

Comment: It seems like you are missing something in your configuration. Paste your .env credentials related to database. PD: Did you run your migrations?

Answer (score 0):

It looking like you are not setting the correct database detail in your .env file.