# Illuminate\Database\QueryException : could not find driver Error

Tags: php, laravel, artisan-migrate

I have an error when trying to execute the command

```
php artisan migrate
```

on my Windows command prompt I've already tried many solutions from the internet by uncommenting

```
extension=pdo_mysql
```

in my php.ini configuration on Xampp but it still not working, is there any working solution to solve this problem?

**ERROR**:

[image]

Comment: Hello, At the end, what did you do for this issue?

Answer (score 3):

go to "config" folder of your project and open database.php

and replace with this code

```
   'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => 'InnoDB',
    ],
```

Comment: it still the same

Comment: please change your php version to 7.2 and restart your server

Comment: I've already installed the Xampp with php version 7.2 but it doesn't work

Comment: did you make  changes in database.php if you did my suggestion is to reinstall laravel and do change in database.php and try php artisan migrate i think this will work

Comment: no, I didn't I just make new database in MySQL and then run php artisan make:controller CreatesContoller and php artisan make:model Article -m to create controller and migration

Comment: please do changes in database.php and try

Answer (score 1):

you can use
First check php version by using php --version and install the corresponding driver.

```
sudo apt-get install php7-mysql
```

Or

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```

Comment: @MiyukiOuka Which PHP version are you using?

Comment: @MiyukiOuka This can happen for a Number of reasons. Either the Default DB type is not set (config/database.php), or the Extension is not enabled, or you HAVE enabled the extension but have NOT restarted XAMPP, or the PATH settings under environment settings are not properly defined.

I suggest you check out this answer which may solve the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25336292/2745485

Comment: I'm using php version 7.3.0

Answer (score 0):

You might need to un-comment `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll`.

Dont forget to restart xampp after un-commenting.

Answer (score 0):

Run Following command:

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
composer update
```

It looks like you have a missing dependency it showing error on your image.

Also Windows users, PDO and all the major drivers ship with PHP as shared extensions, and simply need to be activated by editing the *`php.ini`* file:

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
```

Note: This step is not necessary for PHP 5.3 and above, as a DLL is no longer required for PDO.

Comment: @MiyukiOuka What happened after trying?

Comment: it still the same

Comment: @MiyukiOuka  for testing purpose: create a new database and set in `.env` file after run `php artisan migrate` command execute, try it maybe it helps you

Comment: Okay, when you get a solution, please post as an answer :)

Comment: okay, I think I just realized something, I run php command from my cmd and after I deleting php directory on C:, the php command is gone, so I assume I have to run the command from Xampp shell in order to give a command to php in Xampp service

Comment: @MiyukiOuka  xampp/php/php.ini this is correct directory structure, don't required your xampp installed only C:/ drive , you can other drive also give path of xampp

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand with what you are meaning

Comment: actually, this is my first time using laravel in my project

Answer (score 0):

okay, I think I just realized something, I run php command from my cmd and after I deleting php directory on C:, the php command is gone, so I assume I have to run the command from Xampp shell in order to give a command to php in Xampp service, it works with that way, thank you