# Running laravel on Bitnami WAPP Postgresql

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I'm trying to attach my new Laravel 5.8 project on Bitnami WAPP's (https://bitnami.com/stack/wapp) (v 7.1) Postgresql server

My .env DB config:

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=rest
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=*password defined during WAPP installation*
```

when I run `php artisan migrate` I get:

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = public and table_name = migrations)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show your database.php file.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/2qgPybit

Comment: I fixed the problem with this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51554488/2161119

Comment: Which answer solved your problem?

Comment: @RopAliMunshi I linked the actual answer, I don't know why but php was loading wrong configuration file (php.ini) from old xampp installation

Answer (score 0):

It is a must that you need to uncomment the pdo and postgres shared object in your PHP configuration settings (php.ini).

You need to uncomment the following lines in your `php.ini`

```
extension=pdo_pgsql.so
extension=pgsql.so
```

After that restart your server.