# PDOException::("could not find driver") laravel pgsql

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, wampserver

I need to have Laravel with Postgres

I have wampserver and enabled pgsql and pdo_pgsql extensions for php

my env file is same as below:

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=mehri
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=123456
```

I installed postgres and pgAdmin on windows

Also I added LoadFile "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/8.4/bin/libpq.dll" to httpd.conf

Also I tried to fix this error by adding C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/8.4/bin to environments PATH

when I run php -m , I don't see pgsql

I tried everything but I'm still getting this error

Comment: do you see your postgresql extension in `phpinfo()`

Comment: though I am not sure but [this link](https://blog.lysender.com/2010/08/php-and-postgresql-on-windows/) worked for me when I used to work with win

Comment: no, I don't see

Comment: I already added path, but it didn't work

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/25336292/9471283

Comment: have you enabled in in php.ini ?

Comment: @bhucho I tried this one too, when I want to copy libpq.dll , windows show me error about this file or folder is opened while I exited everything about wamp,

Comment: @Abilogos yes, I enabled , I see Postgres when open localhost in browser but didn't see when printing phpinfo() from laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake, this happened because I've been installed postgres separately on my system. I should install it into wamp or xampp.

anyway, I used bitnami wamp stack as server
https://bitnami.com/stack/wapp