# PHP bin/console doctrine:database:create

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms, symfony-4.3

Using PHP 7.1.33, I was creating a new database for my project and this problem appeared to me

> php bin/console doctrine:database:create
> In AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 79:
>   An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 31:
>   could not find driver
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 27:
>   could not find driver
>
> doctrine:database:create [-s|--shard SHARD] [-c|--connection [CONNECTION]] [--if-not-exists] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--]

Comment: Add some more details, PHP version, Operating system, ...

Comment: @DennisdeBest php version: PHP 7.1.33

Comment: when i pass the command php -m pdo and pdy_mysql already appeared to me and still can't  create the database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: Error \[PDOException\]: Could not Find Driver in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329302/laravel-error-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver-in-postgresql)

Comment: @yivi i already saw those answers and no one of them could help me

Comment: I see `AbstractPostgreSQLDriver` in the messages and `pdy_mysql` in your assessment - please follow [yivi's hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65406078/#comment115635778_65406078).

Comment: Please share more details, like the database configuration within your application

Answer (score 0):

You need php pdo_pgsql extension.

Linux:

```
wget -c https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.1.33.tar.gz
tar -xf php-7.1.33.tar.gz
cd php-7.1.33/ext/pdo_pgsql
phpize
./configure
make
make install

vi php.ini
extension=pdo_pgsql.so
```

Windows:

```
# Edit php.ini
extension=pdo_pgsql.dll
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).