# why queue:listen or queue:work not working in Windows Server?

Tags: laravel, windows-server-2012-r2

I have been having this problem since I deployed my Laravel Project, when I try using the `php artisan queue:listen` or `php artisan queue:work` it doesn't work. Please se the image below.

[image]

Comment: It works, `php artisan queue:listen` will listen... the command listens to the main queue, and if you don't have any job behind, it will not do no anything.

Comment: I actually do have a job, but it just stuck like that on the image. I don't know what's the reason behind it. It really can't process the jobs.

Comment: here's the error I get when using the `php artisan queue:listen`

`local.ERROR: could not find driver {"exception":"[object] (PDOException(code: 0): could not find driver at C:\\wamp\\www\\menu\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector.php:70)`

I just found out about this.

Comment: Take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329302/laravel-error-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver-in-postgresql, the error is different from a queue:listener issue

Comment: I tried the solutions  but its not working, maybe there is something wrong with my wamp server or my Windows Server